# Java regex expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of CSV-extracted data in a `Strg[]`, each element being of the format `[bla bla,bla2 bla2]`. Now I want to get out all the data that is before the comma, while at the same time getting rid of the `[]`. Basically the output should be just `bla bla`.

Could anybody help me? I've been fighting with regex for an hour now.

I have been using this regex: `"^[^\\[,*]"` (It's supposed to mean "select all from beginning except `[` up until first `,`".)

Comment: Show the `regex` with which you were fighting

Comment: Do you even need a Regex. you can simply do 

String str = "[bla bla,bla2 bla2]";
String temp =  str.substring(1,str.indexOf(","));

Comment: Indeed, that was allready sufficient... thank you VERY much!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vB2uL2/1
will also suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Regex

```
String str = "[bla bla,bla2 bla2]";
    str.substring(1,str.indexOf(","));
```

Well If you need a regex a we can do some what like

```
String str = "[bla bla,bla2 bla2]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\[][^\$,]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println( m.group(1));
}
```

The regex used is : `([^\[][^\$,]*)`

If you want to try this regex visit https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
^\[([^,]*),.*\]$
```

Explanation

```
^          beginning of the string
\[         opening [
([^,]*)    capture as much as you can, except ,
,.*        rest of string inside brackets
\]         closing ]
$          end of string
```

Try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/gY4fX1/1).

Answer (score 0):

String temp = str.substring(1,str.indexOf(","));

solves it without using regex